# How to remove quotation from certain json value kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin

I have such json on JS:

```
send({'a': 'value_a', 'b': 'value_b', 'c': c});
```

where с is array with some data.
I have to make similar json for sending it to server. I tried to make by this way:

```
val array = JsonArray()
array.add(id.toString())

val testObj = JSONObject()
testObj.put("testJson",JSONObject().put("a", "value_a")
       .put("b", "value_b")
       .put("c",array.toString().replace("\"", "")).toString())
val finalJsonString = testObj.toString().replace("\\", "")
```

but as a result I receive such result:

```
{"testJson":"{"a":"value_a","b":"value_b","c":"[415918]"}"}
```

I tried to remove quotations from this key but I didn't succeed in it. Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

My variant:

```
return JSONObject(mapOf(
                "testJson" to mapOf(
                        "a" to "value_a",
                        "b" to "value_b",
                        "c" to arrayOf(id)))).toString()
```

Maybe it will help someone else except me :)